# Flyback Frequency Foldback Mode (FFM) and Skip Mode

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, control, flyback

I would like to know why flyback needs to use Frequency Foldback Mode (FFM) and Skip Mode.

I did some research but I don't understand the details of what I've read. Below is a figure that I found in an [ONSemi datasheet for NCP1247](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1247-d.pdf). I would like some explanation for why these modes exist and how they are controlled.

As I understand so far, I only know when the flyback goes to light load, and the system needs to go to Flyback Frequency Foldback Mode (FFM) and Skip Mode.

1. Why do we need to do that?
2. How to understand FFM and skip mode?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency foldback is a method used to improve the efficiency of a converter when the load current is decreasing. When looking at losses in switching semiconductors, some part depends on frequency like switching losses which *directly* scales up or down with frequency. For instance, the loss incurred to the capacitance lumped at the drain node, is \$\approx  \frac{1}{2}C_{lump}V_{DS}^2F_{sw}\$ but the same applies to the average current absorbed by a gate drive which is \$\approx F_{sw}Q_GV_{cc}\$ as shown in the below picture:

[image]

I say approximately because some of these parasitic capacitors are nonlinear and complicate the calculation (see slide 17 of my seminar *[The Dark Side of Flyback Converter](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf)*). As a consequence, reducing the frequency in relationship with the loading condition is a means to reduce these contributions and improve efficiency in light load. Below is a typical curve of frequency foldback:

[image]

You can see a fixed operating frequency at nominal power, e.g. 65 kHz, then the frequency linearly decreases with the delivered power until it approaches the audible noise limit, value at which frequency reduction stops. Then different modes are possible like classical pulse-width modulation or simple skip cycle. Skip cycle is a way to chop a continuous switching pattern into bunches whose width adjusts in relationship with the power. This is what is shown in the below picture:

[image]

Usually, the peak current is compressed before entering skip because of the possible mechanical resonances brought by the discontinuous pattern. These resonances can generate noise and it was the major issue when skip cycle appeared in the 2000's (see more in this literature [pack](https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/NCP1200/NCP1200PAK-D.pdf) about the NCP1200). Various proprietary techniques now exist to reduce the noise while removing pulses.

Some techniques certainly exist to reduce switching frequency and thus stress in fault mode as underlined by *Josh* in his answer but it is not the case here with your circuit where foldback is for improving light-load efficiency only. For your information, frequency foldback in presence of an output short circuit naturally occurs with converters self-relaxing in a quasi-resonant mode.

Answer (score 1):

Working on little context.

1. To prevent short circuit or overload conditions.
2. - Frequency foldback as shown above is simply reducing the switching frequency. Its main purpose is to reduces operating frequency under fault conditions. Decreasing the PWM's oscillator frequency during short circuit or overload conditions and allows the duty cycle to decrease below the value normally limited by other factors.
   - Pulse skip mode can be found in many different types of power converters. The basic concept is to reduce total output stage voltage/power by skipping pulses. Depending on the application there may be other reasons for the occurrence of skipped pulses. These can include reaching an existing current limit, heating above a thermal shutdown limit, increase conversion efficiency and many more.

I suggest sitting down with some application notes and datasheets for Frequency Foldback Current Mode PWM Controllers and Skip Mode Standby PWM Controllers. Such as the UCC3884, TPS61175, and NCP1271 to name a few.